# EF6 Code first Composite Foreign key with Fluent API

Tags: entity-framework-6, foreign-keys, ef-code-first, one-to-one

I am having trouble creating One-one(zero) Foreign key relationship on code first EF6 fluent API

My Entities are

```
 public class Invoice
    {
        public int AccountID { get; set; }
        public int InvoiceID { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public Refund Refund { get; set; }
        internal static void ConfigureModel(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
              modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>()
                       .HasKey(e => new { e.AccountID, e.InvoiceID });
        }
    }

public class Refund 
    {
        public int AccountID { get; set; }
        public int RefundID { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public int InvoiceID { get; set; }
        public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
        internal static void ConfigureModel(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
             modelBuilder.Entity<Refund>()
                      .HasKey(e => new { e.AccountID, e.RefundID });
             modelBuilder.Entity<Refund>()
                .HasRequired(e => e.Invoice )
               // .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.AccountID, e.InvoiceID});
       }
    }
```

I can't define the composite foreign key on Refund table using fluent API

If I change the

```
public Refund Refund { get; set; }
```

to

```
public ICollection<Refund> Refund{ get; set; }
```

Then I can add this relation as

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Refund>()
                .HasRequired(e => e.Invoice)
                .WithMany(e => e.Refund)
                .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.AccountID, e.InvoiceID});
```